# Make a fixed div the same width as parent div and it's padding

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div nested inside a parent div. I want the fixed nested div to be the width of the parent div with the padding. How can I go about this?

```
<div class="panel">
   <div class="fixed">
   </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.panel {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   padding: 10px 60px 10px 10px;
}

.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: The `position: fixed` elements are positioned based on the screen. They are not relative to their parent. So, not possible.

Comment: @PraveenKumar good answer.you can preferably make the parent `div` fixed instead

Comment: @WhiteHox Then it loses its dimensions...

Comment: Thank you. I seemed to have worked around it by making the fixed element have `width: calc(100%-70px);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if not to state paddings for parent, but margins for nested div

```
.panel {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}

.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   width: calc(100vw - 70px);
   height: calc(100vh - 20px);
   margin:  10px 60px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are different between position fixed and absolute and the option you want is absolute with width in 100% like if want to setup nested div to be width as it's parent div also height then the nested div will be setup as position: absolute and here you can see in the given below example with colors of parent and nested div: Hope this is what you were looking for.... :)

```css
.panel {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   padding: 10px 60px 10px 10px;
   background: red;
}

.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   width: inherit;
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
   <div class="fixed">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing with few things:

```
.panel {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 padding: 10px 60px 10px 10px;
 position:relative;
 background:red;
 z-index:9;

}

.fixed {
 background:green;
 position: fixed;
 width:inherit;
 height:inherit;
 z-index:99;
```

}

its always a good practice to differentiate wrapper div and child div with z-index if you want  them on top or behind of another,
and in .fixed you were not giving height:inherit ( or how much you want)

https://jsfiddle.net/ishusupah/wmcw3w6o/1/